# substring charindex not working

Tags: sql-server

DATA:

```
PFP_110
PFP_111
IFC_NP
IFC
```

Expected Output:

```
PFP
PFP
IFC
IFC

  select MemberName,
  SUBSTRING(MemberName,CHARINDEX('_', MemberName),4) from 
  SRC_TEST
```

but not getting the expected output

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what about `LEFT`? More, note that `SUBSTRING` has 3 arguments and you are passing the `_` character as start and 4 characters as length. That means you will get 4 characters at the right of `_`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `LEFT`:

```
select MemberName,LEFT(MemberName,CHARINDEX('_', MemberName + '_')-1) 
from SRC_TEST;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad81a3100874a568a29846f9e784323b)**

Comment: Thanks a lot.select MemberName,
   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MemberName,1,CHARINDEX('_', 
    MemberName)),'_',''), 
    * from EXTRACT_FUND_DIMENSION_FROM_ESSBASE

Answer (score 0):

select MemberName,
 REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MemberName,1,CHARINDEX('*', MemberName)),'*',''), 
 * from SRC_TEST